# using std::transform to add elements of one range to another in place

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, range, addition

in c++ if you had the following code to add elements from two ranges (numbers1 and numbers2), how would you modify it so that the results are stored in numbers2 rather than results?

```
vector<int> numbers1 = {1, 5, 42, 7, 8};
vector<int> numbers2 = {10, 7, 4, 2, 2};
vector<int> results;
std::transform(numbers1.begin(), numbers1.end(),
               numbers2.begin(),
               std::back_inserter(results),
               [](int i, int j) {return i+j;});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the 3rd argument be the `begin` of the output range:

```
std::transform(numbers1.begin(), numbers1.end(),
               numbers2.begin(),
               numbers2.begin(),  // output range
               [](int i, int j) {return i+j;});
```

The requirements for the output range is that it must be as big as the 1st input range, or `numbers1` in this case.